# Vertically align two horizontally-parallel equations

Tags: math-mode, arrays

I am attempting to vertically align two equations at multiple points and I have come up with the following:

```
\begin{array}{rlclcl}
\eta(n)&\equiv&\frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}&\equiv&\sum_{d\mid n}&\mu\left(\frac nd\right)\log_nd\\
\eta(p(x))&\equiv&\frac{\Lambda(p(x))}{\log p(x)}&\equiv&\sum_{c(x)\mid p(x)}&\mu\left(\frac {p(x)}{c(x)}\right)\log_{p(x)}c(x)
\end{array}
```

The problem I'm encountering is that there is too much space between the right-most `\sum` and the following `\mu`, but if I remove the alignment markers then the `\sum` symbols do not align.  Is there a simple way to fix this?  I arrived at this point while trying to get the `\sum` parts to be vertically aligned, and this part of the alignment is what I most want to keep, followed immediately by the `\equiv`s and the `\eth`s (with right-alignment for the `\eth`s).

Is there a simple way to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I would simply center both equation using `gather*` (with `\usepackage{amsmath}`); I think that aligning the `\equiv` and `\sum` signs doesn't add to readability, but rather that it hinders it. Can you add at least the definition for `\eth`?

Comment: @egreg: thank you; I certainly see what you are saying about hindrance particularly due to the extra spacing.  My intent is to convey the similarity of the formulas and I was hoping that vertical alignment would help with that.  So, are you saying that there is no (easy) way to reduce the spacing created by this alignment technique?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'll pick another variable then... I'm just working locally using MathJAX and I'm unfamiliar with where some of the symbols actually come from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that aligning the `\equiv` and `\sum` signs adds to readability; to the contrary, I believe that it hinders it.

Anyway, with some more work one can get the required alignments.

I made also some improvements, defining a `\moebius` command that uses `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, so you can say

```
\moebius{x}        % normal size
\moebius[\big]{x}  % big size
\moebius[\Big]{x}  % Big size
\moebius[\bigg]{x} % bigg size
\moebius[\Bigg]{x} % Bigg size
\moebius*{x}       % automatic sizing, use sparingly
```

The package `array` and `\newcolumntype` are necessary only for the second way of typesetting the formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\moebiusdel{(}{)}
\newcommand{\moebius}{\mu\moebiusdel}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\displaystyle{}}#1<{{}}}

\begin{document}

My proposal
\begin{gather*}
\partial(n)\equiv\frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}\equiv\sum_{d\mid n}\moebius*{\frac{n}{d}}\log_nd\\
\partial(p(x))\equiv\frac{\Lambda(p(x))}{\log p(x)}\equiv\sum_{c(x)\mid p(x)}
  \moebius*{\frac{p(x)}{c(x)}}\log_{p(x)}c(x)
\end{gather*}
With multiple alignments
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{Mr Mc Mc Mc Ml}
\partial(n) &
  \equiv &
  \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n} &
  \equiv &
  \sum_{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$\scriptstyle c(x)\mid p(x)$}]{d\mid n}}
    \moebius*{\frac{n}{d}}\log_nd
\\
\partial(p(x)) &
  \equiv &
  \frac{\Lambda(p(x))}{\log p(x)} &
  \equiv &
  \sum_{c(x)\mid p(x)}\moebius*{\frac{p(x)}{c(x)}}\log_{p(x)}c(x)
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you think you should ‘mathclap’ the sums subscripts?

Comment: @Bernard That would be an option, but I don't like it very much and, anyway, the subscript would be too under the `\equiv`.

Comment: Thank you!  I guess that another option would be to left- or right-align the limits with the `\sum`s, but that seems like it would cause its own problems and not improve anything.

Comment: @Bernard: sadly, it seems that `\mathclap|\mathrlap|\mathllap` are not available in the version of MathJAX I have.  But it's okay, I'll probably come up with a better way of presenting these function definitions before it really matters.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @abiessu MathJax is not LaTeX, although it shares the basic syntax. Most of the TeX constructions that require measuring simply don't work.

Comment: @abiessu: `\mathclap` can be replaced with the longer, but basic `\makebox[0pt]{$ … $}`.

Comment: @egreg among the "better ways of presentation" I am including finding a true [La]TeX editor to use.  I'm reviewing the various questions here and the comparison chart on Wikipedia to see which one could give me a good side-by-side editor/output view.  This was my main difficulty previously which led me to use a web browser with side-by-side `div`s and MathJAX so that I could actually see what I'm writing.